# how to get servlet response in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

how to get servlet response message in javascript variable is there any possible way to get response message in java script?

```
Html:

<form method="post" id="importForm">
Name<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="importScenarioFromServer();">
</form>

javascript:

function importScenarioFromServer(){
    var result = document.forms["importForm"].submit();
}

servlet:

int numberOfRecs = db.setDBValue(dMap);
if (numberOfRecs == 1) {
String result = "success";
response.getWriter().print(result);
}
```

Comment: Use ajax if you don't want to refresh the page, for this [JQuery#ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) will come in handy.

Comment: @arvind i'm sending multipart request but, ajax didn't support multipart requst.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831680/jquery-ajax-multipart-form-data-not-sending-data

Comment: @AMolTate i tried but it's not work

Comment: What problem you are facing for using ajax?

Comment: multipart file condition failed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366903/form-submission-using-ajax-and-handling-response-in-wordpress-website see this you will get some idea

Comment: @AmolTate i need in javascript not in ajax

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374644/how-do-i-capture-response-of-form-submit

Comment: Simply you can not do this using .submit() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented using ajax either in javascript or by using jquery.
we can serialise form in ajax hit and then can get response data from servlet in success event callback function. below is example...

```
function getData()
{
var client;
var data;
var url_action="/temp/getData";
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    client=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    client=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
client.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (client.readyState==4 && client.status==200)
    {
         document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=client.responseText; 
    }
};
data="name="+document.getElementById("name").value+"&file="+document.getElementById("filname").value;
client.open("POST",url_action,true);
client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.send(data);
}


Servlet post method

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    log.info("Good");
    out.println("Good to go");
}
```